# Help proof probability $P((A \cup B) \cap (\overline A \cup \overline B))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to prove that

$$P((A \cup B) \cap (\overline A \cup \overline B))= P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A \cap B)$$

it does make sense when using a venn diagram, but I went to hitting the same wall over and over when trying to prove it algebraically.

your help is really appreciated, thanks

Comment: It was easy enough with venn diagram. All it asked was P(only A)+P(only B). which could be easily shown by $P(A-(A\cap B))+P(B-(A\cap B))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P((A\cup B)\cap(A^c\cup B^c))=P(A\cup B)+P(A^c\cup B^c)-P(A\cup B\cup (A^c\cup B^c))=P(A\cup B)+(1-P(A\cap B))-1=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$$
The first equality consists on applying $P(X\cap Y)=P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cup Y)$. The second one is due to the fact that $A\cup B\cup A^c\cup B^c=\Omega$, $P(\Omega)=1$, $A^c\cup B^c=(A\cap B)^c$ and $P(X^c)=1-P(X)$. We get the last equality by applying the same property that we apply in the first equality.

Comment: thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help... cheers

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
P(A)-P(A\cap B)=P(A\cap\bar B)
$$
and
$$
P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap\bar A).
$$
Since two events $A\cap\bar B$ and $B\cap\bar A$ are disjoint, we have that
$$
P(A\cap\bar B)+P(B\cap\bar A)=P((A\cap\bar B)\cup(B\cap\bar A)).
$$
Using [associative and distributive laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra),
\begin{align*}
(A\cap\bar B)\cup(B\cap\bar A)&=((A\cap\bar B)\cup B)\cap((A\cap\bar B)\cup \bar A)\\&=((A\cup B\cap\bar B\cup B)\cap(A\cup \bar A\cap\bar B\cup \bar A)\\
&=(A\cup B)\cap(\bar A\cup \bar B).
\end{align*}